# Problem installing paid app using google play on mobile

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, google-account

I have previously bought an app from google play and I am trying to install it on a new phone I just bought.

On mobile: When I go on MY APPS on Google Play on mobile, it is there but asks me to buy it again or redeem it.
on PC: when I go on the app's page on Google Play on PC it says the app is installed and compatible with all my devices (but doesn't show this new phone, even though I have logged in there and already used google play).

I have only installed it once, on my previous phone.

Can you please help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Do you use same accounts on both the PC and your mobile? Also, try to visit the playstore website and reinstall the app again by clicking the installed button. It will let you install again and select your new device and see if the app is installed in your phone.

Comment: Yes, it was the same account. I synced everything in my phone and made sure the new phone had been identified in devices on google play on PC. However, nothing worked...

...until now. For some reason, the app is now working and installed and wasn't asking my purchasing it again.

Comment: Did you update something or rebooted your device? How did it solved itself? May be you have done something that sorted the issue.

Comment: well, things I did: I checked it again in the google play on PC, google play may have been updated (I'm unsure I had done it before or after). I did *not* restart my mobile